# Adapting sbit for GCC

Tags: c, gcc, c51

I'm writing a test harness for some C modules, one of which contains the "sbit" keyword. The code was initially written for the Keil C51 compiler, where sbit is used to define a bit within an sfr, more information [here](http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/c51/c51_le_sbit.htm). However, I'm writing the test harness using GCC, where sbit isn't defined. I've tried every combination of static, const, int, and bool, none of which seem to satisfy the compiler. #define doesn't work either, because these variables are assigned values further down in the code.

There was a similar question on this site that suggested that sbit might be too low level for GCC. In any case, is there something I can do to get around this?

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question. Is `typedef unsigned short sbit;` what you are looking for?

Comment: GCC won't understand `sbit` since it is a Keil extension. You might be able to work something out with GCC inline assembly: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Using-Assembly-Language-with-C.html

Comment: @jxh- just FYI, Keil sbit addresses an individual _bit_ in a special function register.

Comment: @Andy- AFAIK, gcc does not support the 8051 so I'm assuming you're porting to gcc for _another_ processor. No other processor will have the same SFRs as an 8051 so you'll need to rewrite these modules anyway.